# Android SoundPool Start/Stop Error

Tags: android, audio, switch-statement, soundpool

I'm new to Stack OverFlow, I appreciate your time and help in advance.

I'm playing around with SoundPool in Android and I've written code that allows to play a sound (which loops) when I click a button. Also, I have a button to stop the loop.

It works fine the first time the stop button is clicked, however, if I try to start the sound again, the stop button does not do anything and the sound continues to loop.

Thanks again,

Arnold

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

SoundPool mSoundPool;
Button b, bStart, bStop;
int mStream = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStart);
    bStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStop);

    bStart.setOnClickListener(this);
    bStop.setOnClickListener(this);

    mSoundPool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

    mStream = mSoundPool.load(this, R.raw.notification, 1);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.bStart:
        mSoundPool.play(mStream, 1, 1, 0, -1, 1);
        break;
    case R.id.bStop:
        mSoundPool.stop(mStream);
        break;

    }
}


}
```

Comment: The ID you pass to `stop()` should be the value returnedby `play()`, not the one you got from `load()` (refer to [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html#stop(int))).

Comment: I didn't realize that I had to add a new int such as mStreamId and set it equal to mSoundPool.play. I ended up making the following changes:

- Added a new variable `int mStreamId`
- Added `mStreamId = ` to `mSoundPool.play(mStream, 1, 1, 0, -1, 1);`
- Changed `mSoundPool.stop(mStream);` to `mSoundPool.stop(mStreamId);`

One quick question. The sound stops fine, but when I try and click the start button to re-play the sound, I have to click it twice for it to actually work. @Michael Any thoughts as to why?

Thanks again, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Resolved - I was getting a `AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12` message. Simply, my file was too big.